# "Layered" slider using slick.js

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to implement a "layered" slider using slick.js.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt7aV.png)

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093653/layered-slides-implementation-using-angular-slick-carousel-component) on stackoverflow but still having some problems. [There](https://jsfiddle.net/fqurka8y/1/) (jsfiddle link) what i have right now. 
The problem is that the right and left slides are cut off. I've tried to increase padding using centerPadding but it didn't work.
Maybe someone had the same problem?
I would be grateful for any advice!

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: true,
  centerMode: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerPadding: '250px',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  speed: 500,
  dots: false,
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  background: pink;
}
.content {
  width: 975px;
  margin: auto;
}
.slick-slide:not(.slick-center) {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
.slick-active.slick-center+.slick-slide+.slick-slide {
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-active.slick-center+.slick-slide,
.slick-center+.slick-cloned {
  z-index: 2;
}
.slick-center {
  z-index: 3;
}
.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 80ms;
}
.slider__item img {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```